# Attribute 'items' must be an array, a Collection or a Map error spring mvc 5

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

I am adding  checkboxes element in jsp file as below

```
SkillOptions:
            
            <form:checkboxes path="skills" items="${theSkillOptions}"/>
```

The Model class is as below

```
public class Employee {

    String employeeId;
    String employeeName;
    String[] skills;
    String country;
    
    
    Employee()
    {
        
        
    }

    public String getEmployeeId() {
        return employeeId;
    }

    public void setEmployeeId(String employeeId) {
        this.employeeId = employeeId;
    }

    public String getEmployeeName() {
        return employeeName;
    }

    public void setEmployeeName(String employeeName) {
        this.employeeName = employeeName;
    }

    public String[] getSkills() {
        return skills;
    }

    public void setSkills(String[] skills) {
        this.skills = skills;
    }

    public String getCountry() {
        return country;
    }

    public void setCountry(String country) {
        this.country = country;
    }
    
    
}
```

The model controller class is below

```
package com.spring.mvc.practice;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Value;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.ui.Model;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ModelAttribute;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;

import java.util.Map;
@Controller
public class EmployeeController {

    @Value("#{skillOptions}")
    private Map<String, String> skillOptions;
    @Value("#{countryOptions}") 
    private Map<String, String> countryOptions;
    
    @RequestMapping("/")
    public String homePage()
    {
        return "main-menu";
    }
    @RequestMapping("/showForm")
    public String showForm(Model model)
    {
        
        Employee emp = new Employee();
        model.addAttribute("employee",emp);
        model.addAttribute("theCountryOptions",countryOptions);
        model.addAttribute("theSkillOptions", "skillOptions");
        return "employee";
    }
    
    @RequestMapping("/processForm")
    public String processForm(@ModelAttribute("employee") Employee emp)
    {
        return "employeeDetails";
    }
}
```

But I get the below error when I deploy the webapp.

```
Nov 30, 2020 12:02:21 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve invoke
SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcher] in context with path [/spring-mvc_-practice] threw exception [An exception occurred processing [/WEB-INF/view/employee.jsp] at line [25]

22:             <br><br>
23:             SkillOptions:
24:             
25:             <form:checkboxes path="skills" items="${theSkillOptions}" />
26:             
27:             <br><br>
28:             


Stacktrace:] with root cause
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Attribute 'items' must be an array, a Collection or a Map
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.form.AbstractMultiCheckedElementTag.writeTagContent(AbstractMultiCheckedElementTag.java:243)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.form.CheckboxesTag.writeTagContent(CheckboxesTag.java:237)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.form.AbstractFormTag.doStartTagInternal(AbstractFormTag.java:87)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.RequestContextAwareTag.doStartTag(RequestContextAwareTag.java:83)
    at org.apache.jsp.WEB_002dINF.view.employee_jsp._jspx_meth_form_005fcheckboxes_005f0(employee_jsp.java:408)
    at org.apache.jsp.WEB_002dINF.view.employee_jsp._jspx_meth_form_005fform_005f0(employee_jsp.java:215)
    at org.apache.jsp.WEB_002dINF.view.employee_jsp._jspService(employee_jsp.java:151)
    at org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:71)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:733)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:477)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:385)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:329)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:733)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.invoke(ApplicationDispatcher.java:712)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.processRequest(ApplicationDispatcher.java:459)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doForward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:384)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.forward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:312)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceView.renderMergedOutputModel(InternalResourceView.java:171)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.view.AbstractView.render(AbstractView.java:316)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.render(DispatcherServlet.java:1373)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.processDispatchResult(DispatcherServlet.java:1118)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1057)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:943)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1006)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:898)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:626)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:883)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:733)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:202)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:541)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:139)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:690)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:74)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:343)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:373)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:65)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:868)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1589)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

Any reason why this error ? I added the model attribute in controller class and accessing it in the jsp page for checkboxes. I am using spring framework 5 and tomcat as the webserver. I am using the the spring form tag library to write the html contents

Comment: do you use thymeleaf in your view ?

Comment: No. I am not using thymleaf in the view

Comment: then how do you set the connection between controller and view

Comment: using Model, which will pass data between view and the controller

Comment: Instead of using model you should use thymeleaf you can check this link more information https://www.thymeleaf.org/

Comment: You didn't add it you added a string not the map. `model.addAttribute("theSkillOptions", "skillOptions");` While you probably wanted `model.addAttribute("theSkillOptions", skillOptions);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that ( in model.attribute method ) you enclosed "skillOptions" in quotation marks.  So you've basically then assigned the String "skillOptions" to attribute "theSkillOptions".

However, Spring demands an array, collection, or a map.

Remove those quotes and let's see what happens.